# ListView con imagenes mias

Tags: android, listview

Tengo 10 imágenes y quiero ponerlas con `ListView`. Si fuera una `activity`, ya estaría hecho pues lo hice en una aplicación, pero ahora son `Fragment`.

```
    String[] menuItems = { "Do some","kkk",",,,,,","Do some","kkk",",,,,,","Do some","kkk",",,,,,","Do some","kkk",",,,,,","Do some","kkk",",,,,,"};


    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.mymenu);

    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menuItems);

    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);


    return v;
```

En vez de `String[]` sería poner algo tipo `Drawable` o similar para que me dejara cargar las fotos mediante `R.drawable.photo1`, `R.drawable.photo2` . Sustituir la linea de texto, pero no sé cómo, o ¿cómo lo tendría que hacer ?

Comment: Hola, veo cerraste tu anterior pregunta la cual iba a responder, en realidad no es complicado lo que deseas, si deseas 10 elementos distintos en tu listado debes tener 10 "items" con diferente layout.

Comment: A ver, no me han dejado editarla... por ejemplo, si quiero poner texto es facil, pongo esto:   String[] menuItems = { "Do some","kkk","..." } y despues ya declaro arrayadapter y todo, eso me sale.

Comment: Pero yo quiero con imagenes, entonces yo quiero cargar R.drawable.photo1, R.drwable.photo2, y en vez de String tiene que ser otra cosa y no sé qué poner, únicamente seria eliminar la linea de introducir String, por la de fotos, como??

Comment: ¿ Sabéis a lo que me refiero ? Con String[] yo cargo texto, lo pongo entre comillas y ya está, y formo mi ListView. En vez de ese texto, quiero imagenes, voy a intentar editar a ver si me dejan.

Comment: Para lo que quieres hacer, es necesario hacer un CustomAdpater. Aqui hay un tutorial para crear un CustomAdapter, siguelo y veras que es sencillo http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67

Comment: Tienes que crear el array como int[], ya que al hacer R.drawable.photo1 lo interpreta como un entero

Comment: Hola Rafa,  veo que abriste nuevamente tu pregunta pero la petición inicial era diferente, 10 items diferentes, confirma si ahora lo que contiene tu pregunta es en realidad lo que deseas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Todos los recursos en tu proyecto, estan definidos por valores tipo entero los cuales puedes ver dentro de tu archivo R.java.

Si los valores son enteros, procede a crear un valor tipo entero conteniendo la referencia de tus imagenes contenidas en sl folder `/drawable`:

```
int[] imagenes = {R.drawable.photo1, R.drawable.photo2, R.drawable.photo3 ...};
```

De esta forma puedes obtener un Drawable del recurso y agregarlo a un ImageView dentro de los elementos en tus ListView, esto se realiza generalmente en el adapter dentro del método `getView()`, tomando la variable `position` como indice para acceder a la imagen correspondiente:

```
//Asigna el Drawable al ImageView.
imageView.setImageDrawable(imagenes[position]);
```

Para esto necesitas crear un customadapter. Como ejemplo puedes usar el comentado en este [articulo](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/) que tiene un ejemplo completo.

Ejemplos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3):

Deberias de crear un adapter para cargar las imagenes ya que por defecto las ListView solo pueden cargar texto.

Puedes hacerlo creando una vista en res/layout/ con el nombre de `listview_img.xml`. A esta vista solo le definimos un `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />
```

Ahora en tu activity, solo tendrias que crear un array con los recursor e implementar el adapter:

```
// obtenemos el listview 
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

// definimos las imagenes que cargara el listview
final int[] resources = {R.drawable.screenshot, R.drawable.cloud_outline_icon_8, R.drawable.screenshot, R.drawable.cloud_outline_icon_8};

// le asignamos el adapter que se encargara de cargar la vista de la imagen y asignarle el id del recurso al ImageView
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2) {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resources.length; // le indicamos la cantidad de elementos que va a cargar
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null)
            {
                // cargamos la vista 
                convertView = ((LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);
            }

            // como la vista es un ImageView lo convertimos y le asignamos el id del recurso
            ((ImageView)convertView).setImageDrawable( ActivityCompat.getDrawable( MainActivity.this, resources[position]));


            return convertView; // retornamos la vista
        }
});
```

Este seria el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]